# get undefined after calling firebase function from android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have android app and i want to send text to firebase cloud function
i call the function like that:

```
    private Task<String> test_function(String text) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    data.put("text", text); //Add the data you'd like to send to the server.


    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("test_function")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    return result;
                }
            });
}
```

and in my index.js of the node.js i try to get the text i sent

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
'use strict';

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase- 
functions

var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: 'https://weddingcalc-ab3d4.firebaseio.com'
});

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
bodyParser.urlencoded();




exports.test_function = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) 
=> {
console.log('text: ' + request.query.text);


});
```

and i get undefined:
i also tried request.body.text and still i gave undefined.
what am i doing wrong?

[picture of the functions log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VqWT.png)